# Googlebot cant access my site webmaster tools reply Unreachable robots.txt

Tags: apache-2.2, robots.txt, googlebot

When I try to fetch my site as a googlebot in webmaster tools it return Unreachable robots.txt, after investigate I understood google bot can see my server:

```
tcpdump | grep google
```

It returns that google can access my server with IP aa.bb.cc.xx or aa.bb.cc.yy.
but there is not anything in access_log or error_log or other apache logs.

```
cat access_log | grep google or cat error_log | grep aa.bb.cc.xx
```

Other bot (bing,...) can access apache but google can't.

There is no problem in my `robots.txt` or its permissions because as you know `robots.txt` is not necessary so I delete it but again webmaster tools returned "Unreachable robots.txt", not 404 not found!

Information about server:

- Server OS : CentOS 6
- Web Server : Apache 2.x
- Firewall : IPTables is stoped
- SELinux is Disabled
- There is not any think else for security on my server.

How can I investigate the problem and is there any other command that can help me to find the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You deleted the `robots.txt` file, of course it's "unreachable" - the 404 error that Google's getting in response to the request for it is because the file doesn't exist.

If the tool requires a `robots.txt` to exist, then you probably need one.